# How to simplify this Rails code -- gets first line from file, parses it and downcases each element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
fields = CSV.parse(File.open(filename).first)[0]
fields.each_with_index do |field, i|
  fields[i] = field.downcase
end
```

I want to get the first line from the line, parse it as CSV and make each element lowercase.

This code seems too redundant to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you consider redundant about this code.  The only thing I would think slightly so is the first line where you get the first line of the file, then parse it into CSV, then ask for only the first element of the resulting array.  On the other hand, if CSV.parse() returns an array of arrays, then there's not much you can do about that other than reading and parsing the whole file, which you don't really want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the looping stuff a bit more concise if you wish:

```
fields.map!(&:downcase)
```

or even:

```
fields = CSV.parse(File.open(filename).first)[0].map(&:downcase)
```

I think you're leaving a file handle hanging there too so you might want to try something like:

```
fields = []
File.open(filename) do |f|
  fields = CSV.parse(f.readline)[0].map(&:downcase)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with what you have but you could say this:

```
fields = CSV.parse(File.open(filename, 'r').first).first.map(&:downcase)
```

Or you could make it easier to read with some methods:

```
def first_line_of(filename)
  File.open(filename, 'r').first
end

def csv_to_array(string)
  CSV.parse(string).first
end

def downcase(a)
  a.map(&:downcase)
end      

fields = downcase csv_to_array first_line_of filename
```